# FFmpeg multiple errors relative to path

Tags: video, ffmpeg, path

I've got a list of videos in the directory:

`C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\part-xxx.mov`,

the filelist:

`C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\list.txt`

which is:

> `file 'C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/zaz/part-1.mov'`
>   `file 'C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/zaz/part-2.mov'`
>   `file 'C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/zaz/part-xxx.mov'`
>   `file 'C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/zaz/part-800.mov'`.

When using the command:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\list.txt -c copy output`

to merge all the parts into a single .mov file, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -f concat -i  
C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\list.txt -c copy output
```

> ffmpeg version N-76331-gf8d429e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
>     configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
>     libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
>     libavcodec     57. 12.100 / 57. 12.100
>     libavformat    57. 11.100 / 57. 11.100
>     libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
>     libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
>     libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>     libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
>     libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   [concat @ 000000bd894daf80] Impossible to open 'C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/zaz/part-1.mov'
>   C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\list.txt: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your video files are in `C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz` you should change the list.txt like this:

```
file C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\part-1.mov'
file C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\part-2.mov'
file C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\part-xxx.mov'
file C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin\zaz\part-800.mov'
```